# user data script in boto not getting executed

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I am trying to spawn an instance with user_data text. I see that the script is there in place, but foes not seem to get executed. I did have a look at other threads here and have already ticked the following  items on the checklist:

1. Verified that the user-data shows up when I 
   `wget http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data`
2. The AMI that I am using is Amazon Linux and not Ubuntu (ami : ami-ccf297fc)
3. I see that the shell script in user data executes well, when done manually. when I do a

   ```
   sh user-data
   ```

   after the wget, it executes smoothly without any issues
4. I verified that the user-data script starts with `#!/bin/bash`
5. I tired with and without base64 encoding the user-data

Let me know if any other details are required.

Also, is it okay to do a sudo poweroff on the init script itself? Could that be a problem? I just need the machine to process some data, put the processed version in s3 and get turned off. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: If one needs to read your question more than once, chances are that need to rephrase it.  (Did you try reading the question yourself?)

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I only figured out now that it was awkward to read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug your script, you can edit the first lines to be:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1
```

After the instance is run, check the log file at `/var/log/user-data.log` to see what errors, if any has occurred.

Comment: it was /var/log/cloud-init.log
The problem was that I was using sudo on all commands without knowing that root executes cloud-init by itself!

Comment: Here's the article where I introduced the above logging line, and how and why to use it: http://alestic.com/2010/12/ec2-user-data-output

Comment: Yes, that's where I got it from, and it helped me a lot :-)